# Encode base64 Url in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string with HTML tags and I want to encode all link urls with base64.

**Example input**

```
<a href="url.com/fqobh2ykscn7" ...>
```

**Expected output**

```
<a href="/link.php?url=base64(url.com/fqobh2ykscn7)" ...>
```

I've tried many methods, for example:

```php
$string = '<img style="border-style: none;" title="Downloading Links" src="/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/download-links.jpg" alt="Downloading Links" /></h4>
<a href="http://url.com/vp1m8880e4hd" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Uptobox</a>

<a href="http://url2.com/fqobh2ykscn7" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Clickupload</a>

<a href="https://url3.com/ian2dpkgyzio" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Usercloud</a>

Password:<span style="color: #b22222;">url4.com</span>';

echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href=([a-zA-Z]+)"? ?(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/', '<a href="\3\4>\5</a>', $string);
```

Comment: If you want answers, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to make it more valuable.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you want to come out? You're probably looking at using `preg_replace_callback()`, in any case.

Comment: I want all urls to encode in base64
like <a href="http://clicknupload.com/fqobh2ykscn7" this url
I want to change it to <a href="/link.php?url=base64(http://clicknupload.com/fqobh2ykscn7)"

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons not to use regex to parse HTML. Instead, we can use the **[DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**.

And to encode with base64, we'll use [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

**Code**

```
$string = '
    <img style="border-style: none;" title="Downloading Links" 
    src="/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/download-links.jpg" alt="Downloading Links" /></h4>
    <a href="http://url.com/vp1m8880e4hd" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Uptobox</a>
    <a href="http://url2.com/fqobh2ykscn7" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Clickupload</a>
    <a href="https://url3.com/ian2dpkgyzio" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Usercloud</a>
    Password:<span style="color: #b22222;">url4.com</span>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', 'link.php?url=' . base64_encode($anchor->getAttribute('href')));
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $result;
```

**Output**

```html
<html><body><img style="border-style: none;" title="Downloading Links" src="/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/download-links.jpg" alt="Downloading Links">
    <a href="link.php?url=aHR0cDovL3VybC5jb20vdnAxbTg4ODBlNGhk" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Uptobox</a>
    <a href="link.php?url=aHR0cDovL3VybDIuY29tL2Zxb2JoMnlrc2NuNw==" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Clickupload</a>
    <a href="link.php?url=aHR0cHM6Ly91cmwzLmNvbS9pYW4yZHBrZ3l6aW8=" target="blank" rel="nofollow">Usercloud</a>
    Password:<span style="color: #b22222;">url4.com</span></body></html>
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/jZcjq4)</kbd>